# Refresh Control image remains the top View

Tags: ios, swift, collections, refresh

I've set up a refreshControl, and I am attempting to add an image to it. However, the image is in front of every other view. I've tried changing the index number and adding it behind the `collectionView`. Here's my current code, the image refuses to move behind the other views no matter what syntax I change it to.

```
func setupRefreshControl() {
    //add refrechcontrol to Collectionview
    self.collectionViewIBO.addSubview(refreshControl)

    self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    let rcImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Rozei"))
    self.refreshControl.insertSubview(rcImageView, at: 0)
}
```

Comment: try refreshControl.endRefreshing()

Comment: I already have that In my `ViewWillAppear`. It changes nothing. I don't see how that would solve this either.

Comment: do you mean that the refreshControl stays on top after you pulled down to refresh?

Comment: not the control itself. just the image I add. When I add a background color I can see where the refreshControl is. When I add an image it stays onto of the entire view, as if its not apart of the refreshControl at all